# Sumar una variable str con una variable int para hacer un valor "a1"

Tags: python

Soy principiante en python y me gustaría saber la manera en la que puedo hacer un programa para sumar una letra y un número (de uno o más digitos) para que me de un resultado parecido a "a1" donde la a es mi letra y el 1 es mi número.
El programa que tengo solo me deja anotar las variables de este modo:

```
letra = a
numero = 1
suma = (letra, numero) = ('a', 1)
```

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en tu pregunta se trata de la **concatenación**, que es una operación que puede *unir dos o incluso más cadenas en una sola string*.

En el lenguaje Python, la concatenación de string se realiza a través del operador de adición `+`.

Al usar el operador `+` para concatenar, los valores diferentes deben convertirse al **mismo tipo**.

En tu pregunta, ambos deben ser del mismo tipo, es decir, del tipo string.

Python tiene algunas formas de realizar la concatenación, entre ellas las [**fstrings**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/), que se consideran una forma de concatenación:

```
letra = "a"
numero = 1

suma = f"{letra}{numero}"

print(suma)
```

A diferencia de la concatenación tradicional utilizando el operador `+`, las `fstrings` ofrecen más posibilidades además de ser más fácil de entender la sintaxis.

- Además de fstring, existe el método [**format()**](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) que formateará strings.

```
letra = "a"
numero = 1

suma = "{}{}".format(letra, numero:d)

print(suma)
```

Ambas las formas son [**module builtins**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) de Python.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

En `python`, el operador `+` sirve para sumar valores numéricos, pero también es el operador de concatenación de cadenas de caracteres (`string`). [Lectura recomendada](https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/paginas-web/desarrollo-web/python-operators/).

Para lograr lo que deseas hacer, lo único que hay que hacer es convertir el valor numérico a `string`, para eso puedes utilizar la función `str()`

Ejemplo:

```
letra = 'a'
numero = 1

concatenado = letra + str(numero)
print(concatenado)
```

Esto imprime:

```
a1
```

Answer (score 0):

Deduzco que lo que quieres es concatenarlos para que aparezcan juntos. Házlo de esta manera:

```
letra = a
numero = 1
suma = letra + str(numero) #con el + concatenas los valores para que aparezcan juntos
#suma = str(numero) + letra si quieres probar a verlo del revés
```

Si lo deseas, puedes personalizarlo como quieras añadiendo espacio entre ambos o símbolos como `suma = str(letra) + "/" + numero`. Usa siempre el `+` cuando quieras concatenar valores

Comment: Tienes que convertir el numero en str, no la letra

Comment: Cierto, un pequeño despiste jeje ya lo edité